# Does GCC have a conventional "likely" path

Tags: gcc, micro-optimization

You can hint give GCC hints about the likelihood of a particular branch taken by using `__builtin_expect`. Without that, does it have any default assumptions. That is, will code like

```
if(error) { /*unlikely path*/ return FAILURE;}
return SUCCESS;
```

perform better/worse than

```
if(!error) {/*likely path*/ return SUCCESS;}
return FAILURE;
```

Comment: No, it will decide what's probably likely/unlikely based on the details of the condition.

I haven't looked at what heuristics it uses, but if there was any real work after the `error` check, I think usually it will compile that to a conditional branch that falls through on no-error and jumps to an extra block past the end of the fast path on error.  (Rather than conditionally jumping over a `return FAILURE` block.)

Answer (score 1):

As any modern compiler, gcc will also perform code analysis. If the code analysis yields any useable / provable information, it chooses some optimization (cf. basic block reordering).
gcc will at least perform static code analysis, while clang (maybe using extensions) will also analyze the execution flow graph.